# Stop TCP server in ESP8266

Tags: tcp, esp8266, sming

I am using ESP8266 WiFi module with the SMING framework. I would like to stop a TCP server. This is how I started the TCP server;

```
tcpServer.listen(8018);
```

What is the code to stop it?

Comment: tcpServer.close(8018, fallback)?

Comment: Let me try out. Thanks.

Comment: @Mohit Sharma, unfortunately, no close function in tcpServer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following and see if it works in your situation:

```
if (tcpServer) delete tcpServer;
```

Hope this helps.